# How could I remove the duplicate shared functions between controllers

Tags: angularjs

I need to use the i18n translation functions betweens controllers.

So each controller should have the  `getCityName` and `getCountryName` to translate it into correct lang.

I tried to use Angular service to reduce the duplication.

As you can see, I still need to define those functions in two controllers separately.

Is it possible to remove the duplication of defining functions in controllers in my case?

Thanks

## Departure.html

```
  <div  ng-repeat="departure in departures_lst">
    <div class="panel-title">
      <h5>{{getCountryName(departure.country)}}</h5>
    </div>
            <li  ng-repeat="city in departure.cities">
              <a ng-click="get_destinations(city)">
                {{getCityName(city)}}
              </a>
           </li>
  </div>
```

## Arrival.html

```
  <div  ng-repeat="arrive in arrives_lst">
    <div class="panel-title">
      <h5>{{getCountryName(arrive.country)}}</h5>
    </div>
            <li  ng-repeat="city in arrive.cities">
              <a ng-click="get_destinations(city)">
                {{getCityName(city)}}
              </a>
           </li>
  </div>
```

## Angular js

```
App.service('I18nService', function () {
    this.getCountryName = function (country_name) {
      return I18n.t("country." + country_name) + country_name
    }
    this.getCityName = function (city_name) {
      return I18n.t("city." + city_name) + city_name
    }
});

App.controller("departures_ctrl", function($scope, I18nService, $location, $http) {
    $scope.getCountryName = function(country_name){
      return I18nService.getCountryName(country_name);
    }
    $scope.getCityName = function(city_name){
      return I18nService.getCityName(city_name);
    }
});

App.controller("arrivals_ctrl",  function($scope, $route, I18nService, $routeParams, $http, $window, $location) {
    $scope.getCountryName = function(country_name){
      return I18nService.getCountryName(country_name);
    }
    $scope.getCityName = function(city_name){
      return I18nService.getCityName(city_name);
    }


});
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid repetition is to add a parameter to the service functions.

You can write something like this:

```
app.controller('FooCtrl', function($scope, TranslationService){

  $scope.getName = function(name, flag){
   TranslationService.getName(name,flag); 
  }

});

app.controller('BarCtrl', function($scope, TranslationService){

  $scope.getName = function(name, flag){
   TranslationService.getName(name,flag); 
  }

});

app.factory('TranslationService', function(){

  return {
    getName: function(name,flag){
      if(flag == 'city'){
          //...
      } 
      else{
        //...  
      }
    }
  }
})
```

And in your HTML view you can use:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="FooCtrl">

  <p>{{getName(obj.city, 'city')}}</p>

</div>
```

If you want to avoid to declare the `getName` function inside the two controllers twice, you can for example assign the function to the `$rootScope` but IMO it's not an ideal solution, as it can make the code less readable.

Comment: thanks~ i will try it later, but it looks a sort of complex and put too many logic on a such simple thing :)

Comment: @newBike glad I helped you. Yes, it's probably a little bit over complex to replace just two functions, but it gives you the possibility to have the your function logic all in one single place instead of two, which in the long run could help you to maintain the code or to implement some new logic.

Answer (score 0):

Though it would probably be mixing 2 responsibilities (see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/222673) you could consider moving the service to inside a directive and use that in your template, like so

```
<div  ng-repeat="departure in departures_lst">
    <div class="panel-title">
      <h5><country-name ng-model="departure.country"></country-name></h5>
    </div>
    <li  ng-repeat="city in departure.cities">
      <a ng-click="get_destinations(city)">
         <city-name ng-model="departure.country"></city-name>
      </a>
    </li>
</div>
```

That way, you just inject your service into the directive and use that to translate your attribute value into the proper one.

If you are just using it for display (i.e. you are not using the converted value for anything else in any other section of your code), I would recommend this whole-heartedly.